# How to find and click on a button element that contains multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Using python + selenium chromedriver.
At a login screen and trying to click the login button however I cant seem to identify the element properly.

Code trial:

```
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tv-button.tv-button--no-border-radius.tv-button--size_large.tv-button--primary_ghost.tv-button--loader')
click(login)
```

HTML:

```
<button type="submit" class="tv-button tv-button--no-border-radius tv-button--size_large tv-button--primary_ghost tv-button--loader">
<span class="tv-button__text">Log In</span>
<span class="tv-button__loader"><span class="tv-button__loader-item"></span><span class="tv-button__loader-item"></span><span class="tv-button__loader-item"></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No doubt that we should always choose css selector over xpath.

But the css selector you are using :  `.tv-button.tv-button--no-border-radius.tv-button--size_large.tv-button--primary_ghost.tv-button--loader`  looks very unstable.

For just login button, you could use :

xpath :  `//span[contains(text(),'Log In')]/parent::button`

Reason behind that you should avoid css selector is that (in this case), that css selector is combination of class name, so in case if any class name changes, you will have to change the locator.

Probability of changing the class name in this case is highly likely. Cause it's made of 5 classes.

Hope this will helps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you miss the `.` at beginning, so Css selector will look for `tv-button` tag instead of class. Try this:

```py
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tv-button.tv-button--no-border-radius.tv-button--size_large.tv-button--primary_ghost.tv-button--loader')
click(login)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would attempt a shorter class selector of

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.tv-button').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Induce `WebDriverWait` to identify the element and then click on that.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.tv-button span')))
print(element.text)
element.click()
```

Comment: Will this basically monitor the button until its clickable?   Could this be used with a webpage that has a submit button greyed out until some condition is met and then is clickable?

Comment: This is the best practise to use WebDriverWait incase your page unable to load in time it is an explicit wait to check whether element is clickable and wait for specified time.

Answer (score 0):

The element is a dynamic element so to locate and click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.tv-button--no-border-radius.tv-button--loader>span.tv-button__text"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='tv-button tv-button--no-border-radius tv-button--size_large tv-button--primary_ghost tv-button--loader']/span[@class='tv-button__text' and text()='Log In']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```